# Maven <executions> and npm build

Tags: java, reactjs, maven, spring-boot, maven-resources-plugin

I have a `hybrid application` : `Spring Boot and ReactJS.`
While r`unning/building/generating WAR`, I have set the `pom.xml` to copy the `npm run build` generated files from `dist` folder to `template`(spring) folder.
But while running `mvn clean install`, file are copied before the `npm run build` command and then the `npm run build` and WAR is generated. That'swhy the frontend files are stale.

My `pom.xml` example is :

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-package</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/public</outputDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/templates</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/dist</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-package2</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/dist/static</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v11.10.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>6.7.0</npmVersion>                          
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>                    
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>test</arguments>
                            <environmentVariables>
                                <CI>true</CI>
                            </environmentVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution> -->
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

How do I configure so that the files are copied after `npm run build` ?

Answer (score -3):

For similar task it makes sense to use Gradle instead of Maven. The tasks are much more flexible.

For example:

```
task buildFE(type: Exec) {
     workingDir '../../FrontEnd'
     commandLine 'buildFE.bat'
}

task CopyJava {
  copy{
    from '../OpenJDK'
    into '../../Release/OpenJDK'
  }
}
```

Comment: can u give it in Maven ?

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.